# How can I convert a Haskell String into a Ptr (Ptr GLchar)?

Tags: opengl, haskell, ffi

I wish to call the function

```
glShaderSource ::
 GLuint
 -> GLsizei
 -> GHC.Ptr.Ptr (GHC.Ptr.Ptr GLchar)
 -> GHC.Ptr.Ptr GLint
 -> IO ()
```

The third argument is the shader program, which is a Haskell string in my program. How do I convert the Haskell `String` into a `GHC.Ptr.Ptr (GHC.Ptr.Ptr GLchar)` so that I can call `glShaderSource`?

Comment: @DavidJohnson: Ordinarily, I'd agree. But this is fairly esoteric, and generally, if you knew where to begin, you wouldn't have to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `withCString` from `Foreign.C.String` to convert a Haskell C string to a temporary C string.  The string is allocated at the beginning of the call and deallocated at the end.

```
withCString s $ \c_string -> let gl_string = castPtr c_string :: Ptr GLchar
                             in glShaderSource a b (foo gl_string) d
```

The cast is necessary because string marshaling functions use the `CChar` type, while GL uses the `GLchar` type.  They are both 8-bit signed integers, and I presume that neither the OpenGL library nor the FFI will change its character type in the future.  If you're concerned about pointer casting, you can write your own marshaling function.

**On pointer-to-pointer types:**

You now have a `Ptr GLchar`.  The right way to make a `Ptr (Ptr GLchar)` depends on what the OpenGL library expects.  For instance, does it expect an array of pointers?  Does it call `free` on some pointers?  Does it write to some of those strings?  The solution will probably involve some amount of memory allocation and pointer copying.

Comment: It is an array of strings, and it does not free them. Full information on what is expected of [`glShaderSource` is available here.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glShaderSource)